# About the induced vector measure of a Pettis integrable function

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, topological-vector-spaces

In what follows, $X$ stands for a Hausdorff LCTVS and $X'$ its topological dual.

Let $(T,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a finite measure space, i.e., $T$ is a nonempty set, $\mathcal{M}$ a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $T$ and $\mu$ is a nonnegative finite measure on $\mathcal{M}$.

A function $f:T\to X$ is called *scalarly integrable* iff for each $x'\in X'$, the composition map
$$x'\circ f:T\to \mathbb{R}$$
is Lebesgue integrable.

A function $f:T\to X$ is said to be *Pettis-integrable* iff it is scalarly integrable and for each $E\in \mathcal{M}$, there exists $x_E\in X$ such that
$$x'(x_E)=\int_E(x'\circ f)d\mu$$
for all $x'\in X'$. In this case, $x_E$ is called the *Pettis integral* of $f$ over $E$ and is denoted by
$$x_E=\int_E fd\mu.$$

**Question.** How can we prove that if $f:T\to X$ is Pettis integrable then the map
$$m_f:\mathcal{M}\to X$$
defined by
$$m_f(E)=\int_E fd\mu, \quad E\in \mathcal{M}$$
is a vector measure on $\mathcal{M}$ which is countably additive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{E_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset\mathcal{M}$ be a sequence of disjoint sets. By $E$ we denote their union. Fix $x'\in X^*$, then
$$
x'(m_f(E))
=x'\left(\int_E fd\mu\right)
=\int_E(x'\circ f)d\mu
=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\int_{E_n}(x'\circ f)d\mu
=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x'\left(\int_{E_n} fd\mu\right)
=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x'\left(m_f(E_n)\right)
=x'\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty m_f(E_n)\right)
$$
Using Orlicz-Pettis theorem for locally convex spaces we can be sure that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty m_f(E_n)$ is convergent.
Since $x'\in X^*$ is arbitrary by corollary of Hahn-Banach theorem
$$
m_f(E)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty m_f(E_n)
$$

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but how do you know $\sum_{n=1}^\infty m_f(E_n)$ converges?

Comment: One can use the Orlicz-Pettis Theorem to deduce this.

Comment: @David Mitra, Actually, that is what I want to see. Kluvanek and Knowles in their book "Vector Measures and Control Systems" at p.22, said (without a proof) that the result follows from Orlicz-Pettis Theorem, of which I do not know how...

Comment: @DavidMitra, thank you, now the proof seems to be correct

Comment: @juniven Given any subseries $\sum_{k=1}^\infty m_f(E_{n_k})$, using the argument above, it follows that for any $x'$, $x'(m_f(\cup_k E_{n_k} )) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty x'(m_f(E_{n_k}))$.  That is, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty m_f(E_n)$ is weakly subseries convergent. O-P then tells you  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty m_f(E_n)$ is norm convergent (unconditional even).

Comment: @DavidMitra, hm but this theorem applies only to Banach spaces, though OP is talking about LCTVS

Comment: @Norbert Ah, I overlooked that. I don't know if O-P generalizes here.

Comment: Ah, perhaps the result on page 95 [here](http://kaltonmemorial.missouri.edu/docs/Cont.Math1980.pdf) ... Also, it is stated in *Vector measures*, Diestel and Uhl, page 34 that the classical statement of the O-P theorem holds in locally convex spaces

Comment: I found an article which says that, "In a locally convex Hausdorff space, each subseries of a series converges with respect to the initial topology of the space iff each subseries of the series converges to the weak topology of the space." Maybe this can help...

Comment: I have downloaded the following article. McArthur, C., On a theorem of Orlicz and Pettis, Pacific Journal of Mathematics, Vol.22, No.2, 1967. Thank you to you both Prof. Norbert and Prof. David for the time shared.

Comment: @juniven, You are wellcome! P.S. wish I could become a professor :)