# About the induced vector measure of a Pettis integrable function(part 2)

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

**Notations:** In what follows, $X$ stands for a Hausdorff LCTVS and $X'$ its topological dual. Let $(T,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a finite measure space, i.e., $T$ is a nonempty set, $\mathcal{M}$ a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $T$ and $\mu$ is a nonnegative finite measure on $\mathcal{M}$.

**Definition.** A function $f:T\to X$ is said to be *Pettis-integrable* if

1. for each $x'\in X'$, the composition map
   $$x'\circ f:T\to \mathbb{R}$$
   is Lebesgue integrable and
2. for each $E\in \mathcal{M}$, there exists $x_E\in X$ such that
   $$x'(x_E)=\int_E(x'\circ f)d\mu$$
   for all $x'\in X'$. In this case, $x_E$ is called the *Pettis integral* of $f$ over $E$ and is denoted by
   $$x_E=\int_E fd\mu.$$

**Remark.** Let $f:T\to X$ be Pettis-integrable. Define
$$m_f:\mathcal{M}\to X$$
by
$$m_f(E)=\int_E fd\mu$$
for any $E\in \mathcal{M}.$ Hahn-Banach Theorem ensures that $x_E$ in the above definition is necessarily unique and so $m_f$ is a well-defined mapping. Moreover, Orlicz-Pettis Theorem imply that the induced vector measure $m_f$ is countably additive, see for instance [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391504/about-the-induced-vector-measure-of-a-pettis-integrable-function).

**Question.** With the above discussions, how do we show that $m_f$ is $\mu$-continuous?

I would be thankful to someone who can help me...

Comment: What is definition of $\mu$-continuiuty?

Comment: I get the entire discussions above in an article, entitled "Pettis Integration in Locally Convex Spaces", by Ali and Chakraborty. They did not put the definition of $\mu$-continuous, I guess they are referring $\mu$-continuous to the absolute continuity of the vector measure $m_f$ with respect to $\mu$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mu(E)=0$. Take arbitrary $x'\in X'$, then
$$
x'(m_f(E))=\int_E (x'\circ f)d\mu=0
$$
then. Since $x'\in X'$ is arbitrary by corollary of Hahn-Banach theorem $m_f(E)=0$. Thus, $m_f\ll\mu$

Comment: Hmnn, great! Your answer fits with the theorem of Pettis given in the book of Diestel and Uhl, entitled "Vector Measures" @ p.10. Thank you

Comment: @juniven you are wellcome! Hope you lear something from my answers, at least Hahn-Banach theorem :)

Comment: I got the whole idea of your answer:) In a locally convex Hausdorff space, the topological dual $X'$ separates the points of $X$ because of the Geometric form of the Hahn-Banach Theorem. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: thanks once again. Best regards!